# como pasar de una activity a otra pero con tiempo sin ningún botón

Tags: java, activity, android-intent

como pasar de una `activity` a otra pero con tiempo sin ningún botón, porque los ejemplos o tutoriales que encuentro solo pasan de una `activity` a otra realizando clic a un botón, gracias.

Actualización:

El ide de android me muestra error en la palabra postDelayed como *cannot resolve symbol 'postDelayed'*

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Intent;
(...)
    private final int tiempoTranscurrir = 3000;
    (...)
    Handler h = new Handler();

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            finish();
            Intent siguiente = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(siguiente);
            h.removeCallbacks(null);
        }

    }, tiempoTranscurrir );
```

Actualización: Cómo tenia errores, ahora estoy intentando con Hilos pero no me reconoce el símbolo Start, será que le hace falta alguna librería, pueden ayudarme? aquí el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola F Pastor, recuerda agregar siempre el código que hayas tratado, eso ayudará a que los usuarios de la comunidad te puedan apoyar de una mejor manera, revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: debes usar en el intent getApplicationContext() y no this, el ódigo debe estar dentro del método onCreate(). El código que agregue en mi respuesta debe funcionar y no deberías tener problema para llamar postDelayed()

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo usar hilos. Si estás usando Kotlin aquí hay un ejemplo.

```
GlobalScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.Main) {
            println("launched coroutine 1")
            Thread.sleep(5000)
            println("Here after a delay of 5 seconds")
        }
```

Thread.sleep(5000) determina el tiempo de espera en milisegundos en este caso 5 segundos.

Comment: Hola intente con las otras respuestas y no me funcionó, estoy intentando ahora con Hilos en JAVA, podrías ayudarme??
    ' Thread t = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
         try {
               sleep(1000);
               Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
               startActivity(i);
               finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    };

    t.start();`//sale error cannot resolve symbol start

Comment: Hola, t.start(); es un método debes colocarlo dentro de un método, en el onCreate despues de setcontentView debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler), después de transcurrido el tiempo llamar un proceso, en este caso abrir la `Activity`:

```
    int tiempoTranscurrir = 1000; //1 segundo, 1000 millisegundos.

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

          //***Aquí agregamos el proceso a ejecutar.

          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityDestino.class);
          startActivity(intent);

            handler.removeCallbacks(null);
        }
    }, tiempoTranscurrir );//define el tiempo.
```

Comment: pues no me reconoce el postDelayed a pesar que tengo importada import android.os.Handler;

Comment: @FPastor si usas import android.os.Handler; reconstruye tu proyecto!